# mach_msg_trap, - (void) mouseDragged and timer performance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, timer, mouse

Leopard 10.5.8, XCode 3.1.1; using runModalForWindow to implement (what is intended to be) a high performance mouse tracking mechanism where I have to do real-time complex bitmap modifications.

The modal loop runs, the timer fires, the mouse tracks... but the performance is abysmal, and it gets worse and worse the longer the runloop goes on. Instead of catching mouse messages every pixel or so, I get them every 5... 10.... 20 seconds.

Instruments shows that the majority of the time during this growing response bottleneck is being spent in mach_msg_trap (and yes, I have the perspective set to the running app), so the impression I am under is that it "thinks" it doesn't have any work to do, despite the fact that I'm dragging the mouse around with the button held down like a crazy person. There are no memory leaks showing up, and in my 8-core 2.8 GHZ machine, there's almost no CPU activity going on.

Again, the app is not spending much time in my code... so it's not a performance problem of mine. I've probably configured something wrong, or failed to configure it at all, or am simply approaching the whole idea wrong -- but I sure would appreciate some insight here. As it stands now, the dispatch of mouse messages and timer messages is absolutely unacceptable. You couldn't implement a crayon drawing program for someone immersed in cold molasses with the response times I'm getting.

EDIT: Some additional info: doesn't happen on my 10.5.8 macbook pro. Just the 8--core, 6-display Mac Pro. I tried taking the display code for the croprect in drawrect out, replaced it with an NSLog()... still drags on issuing mouse updates. Also tried rebooting and running without the usual complement of apps running. And with mirrored displays. No difference.

Imagine dragging a brush across the screen; at first, is paints smoothly, then gaps appear between brush placements, then they get larger, and this goes on until you're only getting one brush placement every 10 seconds. That's how this acts. Using NSlog() and various other tracking methods, I've determined that it is at least at the highest level occurring because the mouseDragged events slow down to a trickle. The question in a nutshell is, why would that happen?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, isolated it -- the problem comes from my Wacom Tablet mouse. Plug in a regular optical mouse, and everything runs great. Same thing on my Macbook pro, using the trackpad. Works fine.

The tablet is a Wacom Intuos 4 with the stock drivers as of January 2011. I'm going over to the Wacom site and reporting this next.

What a nightmare that was. I have spent over 100 hours on this, thinking I'd hosed some subtlety in the app handling, drawing, etc. Sheesh.